# How do I get to open only one detail in b-table?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, vuejs2, vuetify.js

When the button is clicked, the row details are opened. When another row detail is opened, I want to ensure that the open details are closed. One line detail must remain open

[sample screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bypST.png)

As you can see in the example, there is more than one line, while the detail in the first line is open, I want the detail in the second line closed.

```
    <b-table
  show-empty
  small
  stacked="md"
  :items="items"
  :fields="fields"
  :current-page="currentPage"
  :per-page="perPage"
  :filter="filter"
  :filter-included-fields="filterOn"
  :sort-by.sync="sortBy"
  :sort-desc.sync="sortDesc"
  :sort-direction="sortDirection"
  @filtered="onFiltered"
>
  <template #cell(name)="row">
    {{ row.value.first }} {{ row.value.last }}
  </template>

  <template #cell(actions)="row">
    <b-button size="sm" @click="info(row.item, row.index, $event.target)" class="mr-1">
      Info modal
    </b-button>
    <b-button size="sm" @click="row.toggleDetails">
      {{ row.detailsShowing ? 'Hide' : 'Show' }} Details
    </b-button>
  </template>

  <template #row-details="row">
    <b-card>
      <ul>
        <li v-for="(value, key) in row.item" :key="key">{{ key }}: {{ value }}</li>
      </ul>
    </b-card>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

Comment: Your question is too unclear, provide more details to what your asking.

Comment: When the button is clicked, the row details are opened. When another row detail is opened, I want to ensure that the open details are closed. One line detail must remain open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have the custom component code such as `b-table`, but what you would like to do is the following

https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#expandable-rows

1. Basically a separate array tracking which rows are currently open.
2. Assuming `b-table` extends `v-data-table`, pass through the `:expanded` property and add the tracking array.
3. On details open, set the array to `[]`, which should close everything.
4. And immediately afterwards, set the index of the row you want to open to 1.

See the above Vuetify link for an example of how they do it, make sure to toggle the "Single Expand" option.